# How to pass string between C++ (.so) and C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, .so

I want to pass a string back and forth between C++ (.so) and C# **on Linux**. However, I can't really find an example of using PInvoke on Linux (most search results of PInvoke are on Windows). Thus, what is the best way to do this on Linux?

I have tried the plain char* solution, but it doesn't work. I also don't know if it is safe to do it this way, since it is marshaling between un-managed and managed code.

C++

```
//NativeSO

extern "C" const char* IO_String(const char *message)
{
  // I know it is "const char*", but I just want 
  // to express what I want to achieve with this function 
  message = "I changed a C# string"; 
  return message;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("NativeSO")] //let's assume the file name & path are correct
static extern string IO_String(string message);

...

public void test()
{
  string target = IO_String("hi");
  bool isTrue = (target == "I changed a C# string"); 
  print(isTrue); //expect to be true
}
```

I'm expecting the print(isTrue) to be true in C#, but it is not working. The above code's main purpose is to demonstrate the goals that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Pinvoke works on Linux, see Mono (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)

Comment: @Tom I checked that link, but I can't find an example that could fulfill the above situation. perhaps, may you point me out which example from that link can help me out. thank you in advance~

Comment: I have a very limited experience with PInvoke and only on Windows. But, this (char* strncpy (char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);) looks similar to yours.

Comment: P/Invoke works on Linux, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke. In your example are you sure the filename is correct? Also you you just say that you expect your assert to be true, but it’s not. However, you fail to mention what actually happens. What does IO_String returns in C#? Does it return anything? Does it throw an exception? If it’s returning something the P/Invoke generally works, but you are missing something like the proper calling convention. So shouldn’t it be `[DllImport("Native.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`?

Comment: @Tom k, I will take a look into it thanks~

Comment: @ckuri the IO_String() function in C# returns a string from C++ .so, and takes in a string from C#. I think the default "CallingConvention" is fine, because http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T:System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention

Comment: But what is the actual value of `target` you receive? Have you looked at it with a debugger? It not being `"I changed a C# string"` doesn’t really give any insight. Maybe it’s just the wrong charset, i.e. by default C# expects UTF-16, but your C++ may just return ANSI.

Comment: @ckuri  `string target = IO_String("hi");`: IO_string takes in a string, and returns a string. The reason why I check `target == ''I changed a C# string''`, because that is that is the fixed string value I'm returning from the .so

Comment: @Mocha I am understanding what your methods do. But you still haven’t answered the question what the concrete value of `target` is that you get? You should really look into it and debug it.

Comment: @ckuri Im forced to work on Linux and VSCode . So I'm not sure how to check this through debugger yet. Suggestions on how to do it would be extremely awesome. One behavior I caught happening is: things do get crashed sometimes.

Comment: Can’t you do `print(target);` or `Console.WriteLine(target);`? Also for debugging with VSCode see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: @ckuri it is empty and sometime crashes.

Comment: Return type in C# should be `IntPtr` and then convert to a string in C# depending on what encoding you use. What encoding do you use? Also not that your example returns a string literal and so there is no dynamic allocation that needs to be destroyed. Are you always returning a literal? Because if not then this question is a waste of time for everybody (not least you) because it doesn't cover perhaps the key issue. Also, this is a topic that has been covered to death already on SO and I feel sure that more research will help you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What I want to achieve is something like the example. There is a dynamically allocated string in C# that is passed to the .so function. Then I want the .so (in the C++ side) return a string that uses the C# string back to C#. If this topic "has been covered to death", then may you please send me the links on how to do this? Besides that, from what I researched, I am not sure which way it is the "safest" way to marshal between managed and unmanaged code??Appreciated.

Comment: You didn't actually address any of my questions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the default encoding on linux is [utf-8], and yes I do want to return a string literal. However, I don't get the reason why do you must know the "encoding", because I believe the "encoding option" should just be a variable that I can tweak around? Then for your 2nd question, why do you must confirm that I want to return a string literal or not? Weather I return an int pointer to the head of string (char array) or not, I'm still not sure of which way is the "safest" way to do this. Thus, may you please be so kind to leave an example solution? Many Thanks!

Comment: *I believe the "encoding option" should just be a variable that I can tweak around?* If you are returning a literal then you can't, and you need to do manual marshaling, as I said already. I certainly don't want to write an answer until I know what the problem is. Which is why I ask the questions. I still don't know whether or not you always return a literal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan may you please provide both situations (1. always return an IntPtr and 2. always return a literal)? it would be extremely nice if you can also explain the pros & cons between these two options. Perhaps, introduce more options if there are any~ Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not about to write an answer to cover multiple scenarios. One question at a time here. And both of them have been asked and answered many times over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan may you please be kind enough to give me the links to the "questions that were answered multiple times" that fits our discussion?. On the other hand, I think our discussion is still within the single question scope of "what is the best way to pass the string between C++ and C#". If IntPtr are too much to cover, then may I ask your demo answer of "always return a literal"? Many thanks!